# Proof irrelevance of decidable *inequality* in coq

Tags: coq, ssreflect

While trying to prove some equality in ssreflect, I got to the following:

`WTS: forall (a b: ~ false), a = b`

which is basically

`WTS: forall (a b: false <> true), a = b`.

Knowing that the following holds constructively,

`bool_irrelevance (b: bool): (x y: b), x = y`

I got to wonder if it is possible to prove `WTS` constructively.
Since the decidable equality required for  is given as `{x = y} + {x <> y}`, I think it might be provable without axioms. Is this provable?

Also, is it possible to prove proof irrelevance for the prop `False -> False`?

Note, I am indeed fine with using proof irrelevance axiom. Simply asking if there is a way to avoid using the axiom.

Comment: Isn't `false <> true` an abbreviation for `false = true -> False` ? If it is the case you will probably need function extensionality to be able to say anything about the equality of `a` and `b`.

Comment: @kyodralliam yes, it is. Is function extensionality strictly needed to talk about it though? Also, if it is indeed needed, can I prove it only with function extensionality?

Comment: Function extensionality is generally needed whenever you want to say something about the equality of arbitrary functions. And yes you can prove that for any type `A` and proofs `a,b : A -> False` then `a = b` with function extensionality.

Comment: I see, thank you! I want guarantee on whether function extensionality is needed though. On a side note, is function extensionality considered weaker compared to proof irrelevance?

Comment: To see that it is necessary, you can take a model of Coq invalidating function extensionality and check that there exists two terms of your type that are distinct (e.g. take the first $$- \times \mathbb{B}$$ model of [this paper](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01445835/document)). In general function extensionality and proof irrelevance are probably incomparable, but if you restrict function extensionality to implication between propositions, then it is trivially implied by proof-irrelevance.

Comment: @kyodralliam Thank you, this answered the question greatly! Could you formulate it into an answer?